# Token based authentication in php symfony 2

Tags: php, api, symfony, security, authentication

I am building a rest api and web app in symfony 2. My rest api will be consumed by mobile application and it is not a public api. I am using token based authentication with tokens stored in a database.

My table schema is shown below:

```
|---users----|     |---identities---------|
|pk id       |     |pk  id                |
|   email    |     |    token             |
|   password |     |    device            |
|------------|     |fk  user_id           |
                   |    token_createdDate |
                   |----------------------|
```

My authentication process involves following steps:

1. There is a login form with username and password in android app.App sends login request(POST) along with the device name in user-agent request header to My php api and url looks like this:/api/v1/login. If authentication is successful, I send back a json response with token. sample json response is shown below:

```js
{
    "token":"1325asd3434asfFF34d65",
          "user" :{
                "id":32,
                "email":"sample@eg.com",
                "role" :"customer" 
          }
 }
```

2. Now android app uses this token  by including it within request header to access secured api resource. My protected resource url is like this: /api/v1/hello. php api reads the token and user-agent request headers and then validates if it exists in my table "identities". user-agent request header maps to device column in my table "identities".

What are the vulnerabilities of my authentication system here for the rest api ?

update:
I came across FosOAuthBundle but I am confused whether it can be used for my scenario. My api will not be public. My android app will provide login interface with login and password form. Is it possible to do this with FOSOAuthBundle ?

Comment: Do you use one token for the session or change it with every request?

Comment: I am on the design stage, so I am open to any change necessary. Currently, I am thinking of expiring tokens after some period (2 months per say). The tokens that my android app receives at the time of initial authentication will be saved by my app. Then my app uses this token to login until the token expires.

Comment: @pradip Using https with your system might be a good way to go I guess. I'm doing the same thing now. So how did you handled that in the end ? Especially how did you implement the token part ?

Comment: I am using the same structure. I also used jwt for tokens. With jwt you dont necessarily need to store it in database. I stored it in database to maintain the list of compromised tokens which allows me to revoke the token. https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt